# ActiveAdmin very slow in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, reload

I have an app that use ActiveAdmin gem. 
We have actually 3 namespace and more than 100 `ActiveAdmin.register Model`
rails 5.0.7
activeadmin 2.4

The app run pretty well in production, however when we are in development mode, every time code changes, the reload is very slow.

A reflexion track may be not related:
I deep dived a bit, it seems that the code start to reload once for the html part of the "browser request" but afterward it reloads multiple times for each asset the page ask for. And it does at the same time. The code reloaded many time at once, the reload start to be very slow.

Here the output logs when I just make a code modification :

```
Started GET "/admin/tickets" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:35:23 +0200
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
Processing by Admin::TicketsController#index as HTML
  AdminUser Load (4.8ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering /Users/baptibenz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb
   (2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "tickets" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "tickets" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
   (2.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tickets"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "tickets" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Ticket Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "tickets".* FROM "tickets" ORDER BY "tickets"."id" desc LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Listing Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 22015], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Team Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TicketCategory Load (9.6ms)  SELECT  "ticket_categories".* FROM "ticket_categories" WHERE "ticket_categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered admin/tickets/_index.arb (179.4ms)
  TicketCategory Load (5.0ms)  SELECT "ticket_categories".* FROM "ticket_categories"
  Team Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams"
  AdminUser Load (28.2ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users"
  Rendered layouts/_analytics.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/baptibenz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (470.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 649ms (Views: 466.9ms | ActiveRecord: 68.7ms)


   (3.1ms)  BEGIN
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
Started GET "/assets/jquery.xdan.datetimepicker.css" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:35:36 +0200
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
Started GET "/assets/active_admin.js" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:35:43 +0200
   (2.1ms)  BEGIN
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
Started GET "/assets/active_admin/print.css" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:35:54 +0200
Started GET "/assets/active_admin.css" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:35:54 +0200
   (3.4ms)  BEGIN
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
   (2.4ms)  BEGIN
   (4.5ms)  BEGIN
   (5.2ms)  COMMIT
   (3.8ms)  COMMIT
Started GET "/assets/active_admin/orderable.png" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:36:35 +0200
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
Started GET "/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow.gif" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:36:56 +0200
   (3.1ms)  BEGIN
   (3.1ms)  COMMIT
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
Started GET "/assets/chosen-sprite@2x.png" for ::1 at 2020-04-21 11:37:19 +0200
   (2.9ms)  BEGIN
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
Creating scope :customer_relations. Overwriting existing method AdminUser.customer_relations.
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder::DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS
/Users/baptibenz/dev/backend/app/admin/lib/component.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_COLUMNS_OPTIONS was here
   (2.2ms)  BEGIN
   (4.9ms)  COMMIT
```

As you can see in dates it's very slow

Tell me if you need more information :-)

Comment: add your dev log from when you git the browser until it finish to load.

Comment: @matanco added :-)

Comment: Doesn't look slow to me, this log is after making a change?

Comment: @matanco yes it's after making the change : between the start of the first call `GET "/admin/tickets"` (2020-04-21 11:35:23) and the start of the last call (every cal trigger reload of the app) : `GET "/assets/chosen-sprite@2x.png"` (2020-04-21 11:37:19) I waited ~2min for the page finish loading

Comment: Can you show me this scope: `AdminUser.customer_relations` and what the table size on your dev?

Comment: The scope is very simple: `  scope :customer_relations, -> { where(team: CUSTOMER_RELATIONS) }
`, and the table ~100 row. I think the issue is not that this scope is slow but more that all code base is reloader  multiple time isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have run into [ActiveAdmin#5787](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5787). TL;DR this went away with Rails 5.2 and ActiveAdmin 2.6.

Comment: Also, FWIW, one strategy I've seen at larger shops is to use environment variables to selectively register only a subset of the resources in development.